# Trying to make a Paper, Rock, Scissors game on my own

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a javascript and jQuery beginner (as in barely a week in), and I need some experienced people to tell me what's wrong with this code. Clicking a div does nothing. I could google for hours, but you guys could probably see the issue(s) way quicker, and I'll be able to learn from the mistake(s) and move on. In my code, I replaced the very last command with "console.log" and copy/pasted everything into textedit to see if it would give me "answer" in the console when I clicked. But I got nothing. Thank you guys ahead of time.

My code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Euroclydon37/CUTez/14/).

... and here

```
var box = "div";

$(document).ready(

function () {
    $(box).fadeTo(1000, 0.8);
});



$(box).click(

function () {
    var userchoice = this.id;
    var answer;
    var computerchoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);

    if (computerchoice === 1) {
        computerchoice = "rock";
    }

    if (computerchoice === 2) {
        computerchoice = "paper";
    }

    if (computerchoice === 3) {
        computerchoice = "scissors";
    }

    if (userchoice === computerchoice) {
        answer = "It's a tie.";
    }
    if (userchoice === "rock") {
        if (computerchoice === "paper") {
            answer = "Computer Wins with " + computerchoice + ".";
        } else {
            answer = "You win with " + userchoice + ".";
        }
    }
    if (userchoice === "paper") {
        if (computerchoice === "scissors") {
            answer = "Computer Wins with " + computerchoice + ".";
        } else {
            answer = "You win with " + userchoice + ".";
        }
    }
    if (userchoice === "scissors") {
        if (computerchoice === "rock") {
            answer = "Computer Wins with " + computerchoice + ".";
        } else {
            answer = "You win with " + userchoice + ".";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML(answer);
});
```

Comment: Open your browser's error console. Read the error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check your browser's JS console you'll see this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'innerHTML' of object #<HTMLHeadingElement> is not a function
```

This is telling you that `.innerHTML` is a property that you would assign a value to, not a function to be called, so you need to change this line:

```
document.getElementById("header").innerHTML(answer);
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = answer;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CUTez/15/

But since you're using jQuery, you can do this:

```
$("#header").html(answer);
```

Note also that if you run the same code outside jsfiddle you will need to move the `$(box).click(...)` code inside the document ready handler, or put the whole script element at the end of your page just before the closing `</body>` tag, otherwise the `$(box)` part won't find any elements because they won't have been parsed yet. (It works in the fiddle because by default jsfiddle puts all of the code in an onload handler.)

Comment: Sweet! That's really encouraging. I expected alot more errors than that, which is why I posted here rather than searching through google. But I opened it in google chrome and I didn't see any errors showing. Maybe I was looking in the wrong place? Perhaps you could post a link I can go to to really learn what I'm looking at in that menu? In any case, thanks for the help.

Comment: The error in question only occurs when you click. In Chrome press F12 to open the dev tools, then click "console". (Any errors will displayed in the same console that `console.log()` logs to.)

Comment: Oh, that makes total sense, now. I had just assumed it would show any and all errors. Thanks, man. You've been super helpful. I'm gonna go do some googling and get super familiar with the console. Maybe I'll be able to find my own errors.